# How to create groups like whatsapp with ejabberd?

Tags: php, xampp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-api

I need to ask few questions:

a. How can I create whatsapp like groups?

b. How can I implement group chat similar to whatsapp?

Right now I am creating rooms and invite users into them. Users automatically removed from room,when users go offiline. 
But in whatsapp group chat users still remain in group after logout or not connected and when users come online, they get all offline messages.

Please suggest me how can I create group chat similar to whatsapp group chat where group owner can add users, ban, UN-ban and get off-line message as well.

Please help me giving few tips and links to study.

Regards,

Sandeep Kumar Thakur

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ejabberd Muc/Sub feature to build groups like Whatsapp: https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/proposed-extensions/muc-sub/

It has been designed with that use case in mind.

Comment: Sir thanks for reply. Can you let me know whether  it is possible using php server side to maintain users in room after logout.

Comment: What do you mean by maintain ? The role of pubsub is to make sure users is still a subscriber after logout.

Comment: Maintains means user should not removed from the rooms if go off-line.

Comment: Just subscribe to the MUC room then. That's the purpose of MUC/Sub.